# ImportError: No module named anyjson while starting Celery within Flask application

Tags: python, celery

I am trying to work with Celery within a Flask application. For this, I followed [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/celery/) flask guide. The issue is that when starting up the flask application, I get the following error:

```
.../kombu/serialization.py", line 310, in register_json
    from anyjson import loads as json_loads, dumps as json_dumps
ImportError: No module named anyjson
```

This seems to be a dependency issue on Kombu, a Celery dependency (I am using 3.1.10 celery version), [which](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1345) was reported some time ago.

Does anybody know how to get rid from this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you tried installing anyjson module `pip install anyjson`?